# two events firing, How can i ignore disable/unbind the other

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this sudo html

```
<ul>
<li id="434" class="home-page-item" >
<div id="x_434" class="home-page-item-foot remove-tile"></div>
<div class="home-page-item-div">
    </li>
 </ul>
```

i then have these onclicks

```
$( '.remove-tile').live("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      removeTile();
});  

$( ".home-page-item" ).live("click", function(event){
      console.log("Here as well");
      do_some_otherstuff():
});
```

The problem i am having is if the person clicks on the remove-tile div, the .home-page-item onclick is also fired after. Is there a way to prevent the second home-page-item firing?
I think maybe unbind, but not sure how to use it

Thanks

Comment: $('remove-title).unbind('live') - this will unbind. If you are with 1.8 or later version use on/off instead. Also, just for your information, jQuery "unbind" works only with event bind with jQuery itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( '.remove-tile').live("click", function(event){
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      removeTile();
});  

$( ".home-page-item" ).live("click", function(event){
      console.log("Here as well");
      do_some_otherstuff():
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return false in functions; It is happening because of event propagation . in `jQuery` you can use return false to prevent deafult (`preventDefault`) and event propagation.

```
$( '.remove-tile').live("click", function(event){
      removeTile();
      return false;
});  

$( ".home-page-item" ).live("click", function(event){
      console.log("Here as well");
      do_some_otherstuff():
      return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of event bubbling..
Add  `event.stopPropagation();`  into your click event

```
$('.remove-tile').live("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    removeTile();
});
```